# sfValidatorDoctrineUnique fails since I have a custom setField()

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, validation

A **user** can post a **music link**, as the music provider can be varied (Youtube, Deezer, Soundcloud, etc..), I have a **custom validator** and a custom **setLink()**.
In my database, a link is the video's id (Example for youtube : CWMYxYoaRBQ)

But the consequence is that my sfValidatorDoctrineUnique does not work anymore.

My validator :

```
<?php

class videoValidator extends sfValidatorUrl
{
  protected function configure($options = array(), $messages = array())
  {
    parent::configure($options, $messages);
    $this->setMessage('invalid', 'Error message.');
  }

  protected function doClean($url)
  {
    $videoProvider = new videoProvider($url);
    if (false === $videoProvider->isValid())
    {
      throw new sfValidatorError($this, 'invalid', array('value' => $url));
    }

    return $url;
  }
}

?>
```

My videoProvider class :

```
class videoProvider
{
  private $url;
  private $providers = array('youtube','deezer','soundcloud');
  private $youtubePattern = '%^# Match any youtube URL
      (?:https?://)?  # Optional scheme. Either http or https
      (?:www\.)?      # Optional www subdomain
      (?:             # Group host alternatives
        youtu\.be/    # Either youtu.be,
      | youtube\.com  # or youtube.com
        (?:           # Group path alternatives
          /embed/     # Either /embed/
        | /v/         # or /v/
        | /watch\?v=  # or /watch\?v=
        )             # End path alternatives.
      )               # End host alternatives.
      ([\w-]{10,12})  # Allow 10-12 for 11 char youtube id.
      $%x';
  private $deezerPattern = '/\d+/';
  private $soundcloudPattern = '[\w-]+/[\w-]+$';

  public function __construct($url)
  {
    $this->url = $url;
  }

  /**
   * @return true / false
   */
  private function checkYoutube()
  {
    return preg_match($this->youtubePattern, $this->url) ? true : false;
  }

  /**
   * @return true / false
   */
  private function checkDeezer()
  {
     // A Deezer URL has this format : http://www.deezer.com/track/61340079

     return preg_match($this->deezerPattern, $this->url) ? true : false;
  }

  /**
   * @return true / false
   */
  private function checkSoundcloud()
  {
     // A Soundcloud URL has this format : http://soundcloud.com/[A-Z Artist]/[A-Z Title]

     return preg_match($this->soundcloudPattern, $this->url) ? true : false;
  }

  /**
   * @return true / false
   */
  public function isValid()
  {
    // check all video provider as you do in your validator
    // so it will return true if it find one, otherwise false

    foreach ($this->providers as $provider)
    {
      $function = 'check'.ucfirst($provider);

      if (true === $this->$function())
      {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }

  /**
   * @return string
   */
  public function getId()
  {
    if ($this->checkYoutube() && preg_match($this->youtubePattern, $this->url, $matches))
    {
      return $matches[1];
    }

    if ($this->checkDeezer() && preg_match($this->deezerPattern, $this->url, $matches))
    {
      return $matches[1];
    }

    if ($this->checkSoundcloud() && preg_match($this->deezerPattern, $this->url, $matches))
    {
      return $matches[1];
    }
  }

  /**
   * @return string
   */
  public function getProvider()
  {
    if ($this->checkYoutube())
    {
      return 'youtube';
    }

    if ($this->checkDeezer())
    {
      return 'deezer';
    }

    if ($this->checkSoundcloud())
    {
      return 'soundcloud';
    }
  }
}
```

My Song class :

```
class Song extends BaseSong
{
  public function setLink($value)
  {
    // only perform this tweak if the value is a http link
    if (preg_match('/^http/i', $value))
    {
      $videoProvider = new videoProvider($value);

      // define url id
      parent::_set('link', $videoProvider->getId());

      // define type id
      $provider = $videoProvider->getProvider();
      $type     = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Type')->findOneByName($provider);

      parent::_set('type_id', $type->getId());
     }
  }
}
```

What I think is sfValidatorDoctrineUnique tries to compare a full URL (Form field) to a video id (Database field). How can I fix it ?

Comment: Where and how did you define your `sfValidatorDoctrineUnique`?

Comment: `$this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(new sfValidatorDoctrineUnique(array('model' => 'Song', 'column' => 'link'), array('invalid' => 'Already added.')));` in my `AddSongForm.class.php`

Comment: @j0k : Is it possible to use sfValidatorDoctrineUnique somewhere else ? Or, is it possible to check if the video's id already exists in the videoValidator and throw my own exception ?

Comment: Yep, you can check the video id in your videoValidator, it could be an option

Comment: @j0k : May I post the code in my question, an answer or on pastebin ?

Comment: Depends. If the code solve your problem: an answer, if your code updated your question: update the question.

Comment: @j0k : Just wanted to show you the code before making mistakes : http://pastebin.com/xSyMbYyK. Thanks.

Comment: `$url->getId()` -> `$videoProvider->getId()`. `if (!empty($unique))` -> `if (!$unique instanceof Song)`

Comment: Validator does not accept **unique** as an error message..

Comment: Use a different one then

Comment: Same issue, I've searched on the Internet and it seems validators only accept **required** and **unique**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution, tested and working.

```
class videoValidator extends sfValidatorUrl
{
  protected function configure($options = array(), $messages = array())
  {
    parent::configure($options, $messages);
    $this->setMessage('invalid', 'Le lien n\'est pas valide. Veuillez entrer un lien Youtube, Deezer ou Soundcloud.');
  }

  protected function doClean($url)
  {
    $videoProvider = new videoProvider($url);
    if (false === $videoProvider->isValid())
    {
      throw new sfValidatorError($this, 'invalid', array('value' => $url));
    }

    $unique = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Song')->findOneByLink($videoProvider->getId());
    if (!empty($unique))
    {
      return $videoProvider->getId();
    }
    return $url;
  }
}
```

I return video's id the video already exists in database. Then, I think that sfValidatorDoctrineUnique is able to perform its test.

Does this seem logic to you ?

Comment: Yep as I said, it's an option